# Does there exist a measure $\mu$ on $([0,1],\mathfrak B_{[0,1]})$ such that $\mu(\text {Cantor Set})=1$ and $\mu (\{x\})=0$ for every $x \in [0,1]$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> Does there exist a measure $\mu$ on $([0,1],\mathfrak B_{[0,1]})$ such that $\mu(\text {Cantor set})=1$ and $\mu (\{x\})=0$ for every $x \in [0,1]$?

If there is no assumption on measure of singleton we can take $\mu$ to be Counting measure but it does not with the assumptions.I know that the Lebesgue measure of Cantor set is zero,i think [Riesz Representation theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RieszRepresentationTheorem.html) should help here but i am unable to see it.Any ideas?

Comment: See [Cantor distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_distribution).

Comment: Hausdorff measure where $\alpha=\log2/\log3$